# CASSANDRA_HOME variable not found

Tags: cassandra

I am not able to find CASSANDRA_HOME variable anywhere being set in the CASSANDRA installed path.
I  could guess that it is my installation directory of cassandra because the log files are created in the installed_dir/logs.
Where can I find CASSANDRA_HOME being set?

Comment: What instructions did you followd to install cassandra? You need to put more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't provided a lot of information but I'll try and answer.

`CASSANDRA_HOME` is set in `cassandra.in.sh` or `cassandra.bat` if you are running on windows. If `CASSANDRA_HOME` isn't set it sets it to the parent of the directory that the script is running in.

I'm assuming that you are running from a tarball installation since you say that the log files are enter up under your install directory, hence your `bin` directory is directly under the install directory.